# jqgrid: Search toolbar is not working properly in date column

Tags: jquery

I have multiple columns in my jqgrid but search function does not work just in date columns. it gets data from stored procedure such as "2017-03-03 12:12:12" and shows it to grid. when i search "2017", it does not show me anything.

Here is the part of my code

```
`<cc1:JQGridColumn 
         DataField="Date" 
         HeaderText="Date"
         Editable="true"
         DataType="Datetime"
         Sortable="true"
         Searchable="true"
         SearchToolBarOperation="BeginsWith"
         Width="140" >
</cc1:JQGridColumn>
```

`

I have tried

・modifying stored procedure and convert datetime to varchar like"20170908"

・changing SearchToolBarOperation="BeginsWith" to SearchToolBarOperation="Contains" and it only made it able to search the first 4 numbers like "2017". when i typed "201708", it didnt work.

・also tried "IsEqualTo" "IsGreaterThan" on SearchToolBarOperation but none of them worked

i want to be able to do begins-with match so i want it to show me the data when i type such as "2017-08" or "2017" or "2017-08-08".

thank you so much for reading my question. i hope you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If the search is performed at server, then you need to fine tune your search code at server. jqGrid just sends operation and string to the server and expect result.

To demonstrate the problem, execute the stored procedure in the console with the date parameters as build-ed when the search is on and see the result - it should be the same as performed to the grid.

I recommend you to read your db  server documentation on how to search on date fields and see if at all begin with and similar commands are applicable

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. I executed a query in stored procedure and saw how i can get results. it turned out that i can search in these format like  ’2017/12/12’ or  '2017/12/12 12:12:12' but NOT '2017/12'. i want to be able to get results in that format also. Is there any way that makes it possible?

Comment: Depending on the DataBase used you can convert the date field to  string and use it in the search. In MySQL db this is the CAST function in PostgresSQl this is to_char function. Look in your SQL documentation for converting functions.